# ExtJS 4.2 - Bind Date Picker to Grid - Newbie Q

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am new to ExtJS 4 and struggling at times with the learning curve.  I have followed the documentation on sencha's site for MVC concept for basic structure of my app, however I am having difficulty determining where/how to implement certain components/handlers/listeners as I don't quite have the feel for this frame work yet.

So, here is my question.... (Yes I did look at other posts on SO but I think at this point I am too stupid to identify and apply what similar posters may have come accross to solve my issues)

How do I bind a date field in my grid to the date picker date that is selected and vice versa? If I select a date in my date picker I would like to have my grid load relevant rows from my db.  If I select a row in my grid I would like to see the date picker reflect the date in the selected row.

Can someone give me a narrative of the approach i should be taking? I have seen some code examples but I don't clearly see an obvious preferred method or the way it should be done. If there is a link someone can give me to look at I will be happy to study.

This is my first post on SO so please forgive me for any etiquette I am lacking as well as other annoying things.  Thanks in advance!

Store:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'AM.model.User',
autoLoad: true,
autoSync:true,
pageSize:50,
proxy:
{
    type: 'ajax',
    api:
    {
        read: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2.cfc?method=getContent',
        update: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2-post.cfc?method=postContent'
    },
    reader:
    {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success',
        totalProperty : 'dataset'
    }}
```

});

model:

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        {name: 'message_id',type: 'textfield'},
        {name: 'recip_email',type: 'textfield'},
        {name: 'unix_time_stamp',type:'datefield'}
        ]
```

});

View:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.userlist',
title: 'All Users',
store: 'Users',
plugins:[Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {clicksToEdit: 1})],
dockedItems: [{ xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: 'Users',
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayMsg: 'Displaying Records {0} - {1} of {2}',
                displayInfo: true}],


initComponent: function() {

    this.columns = [
                    Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer',
                        {
                        resizable: true,
                        resizeHandles:'all',
                        align: 'center',
                        minWidth: 35,
                        maxWidth:50
                        }),
                    {
                    header: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'message_id',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor:'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    menuDisabled:true
                    },
                    {
                    header: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'recip_email',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor:'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    menuDisabled:true
                    },
                    {
                    header: 'Date Time',
                    dataIndex: 'unix_time_stamp',
                    width: 120,
                    menuDisabled:true,
                    renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
                        field:{ xtype:'datefield',
                                autoSync:true,
                                allowBlank:false,
                                editor: new Ext.form.DateField(
                                        {format: 'm/d/y'})  }
                    }];



    this.callParent(arguments);


},
```

});

Viewport:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
```

// This array is for testing.
dateArray = ["12/14/2013","12/16/2013","12/18/2013","12/20/2013"];

Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: ['Users'],

```
launch: function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {

    layout: 'border',

     items:
        [
            {

            region: 'center',
            //layout:'fit',
            title:'The Title',
            xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
            activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default
            items:
            [{
                xtype: 'userlist',
                listeners:
                {
                    select: function(selModel, record, index, options)
                    {
                        // do something with the selected date
                        // Ext.Msg.alert(record.data.message_id, record.data.recip_email +'<br> ' + record.data.unix_time_stamp);
                    }
                }
            }]

            },
            {
            region: 'west',
            layout:'fit',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activetab:0,
            collapsible:false,
            split: false,
            title: 'The Title',

            width:178,
            maxWidth:400,
            height: 100,
            minHeight: 100,
            items:
            [
            {
                title: 'Tab 1',
                xtype:'panel',
                items:
                    [{
                    xtype: 'datepicker',
                    title: 'mydate',
                    minDate: new Date('12/15/2013'),
                    maxDate: new Date(),

                    // Disable dates is set to invert dates in array
                    disabledDates:["^(?!"+dateArray.join("|")+").*$"],
                    // disabledDates:["^("+dateArray.join("|")+").*$"],

                    handler: function(picker, date)
                            {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            Ext.Msg.alert('date picker example in init2.js');
                            }
                    }]
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html: 'ers may be added dynamically  - Others may be added dynamically',
            }

            ]

            }
        ]

    });
}
```

});

Update to Datepicker in Viewport:

One additional note is that i notice a property attribute in the JSON packet that has the date included even without making you suggested changes to the store.  I notice there may be a bug in the link you provided?? If i set to false or remove it altogether from my store it has same behavior and is included in my JSON packet.

Do I need to encode the url also? when I click on a row in my grid and hit the update button i recive the grid row on my server side with what appears to be already url encoded by extjs perhaps?

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
```

// This array is for testing.
dateArray = ["12/14/2013","12/16/2013","12/18/2013","12/20/2013"];

Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: ['Users'],

```
launch: function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {

    layout: 'border',

     items:
        [
            {

            region: 'center',
            //layout:'fit',
            title:'The Title',
            xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
            activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default
            items:
            [{
                xtype: 'userlist',
                listeners:
                {
                    select: function(selModel, record, index, options)
                    {
                        // do something with the selected date
                        // Ext.Msg.alert(record.data.message_id, record.data.recip_email +'<br> ' + record.data.unix_time_stamp);
                    }
                }
            }]

            },
            {
            region: 'west',
            layout:'fit',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activetab:0,
            collapsible:false,
            split: false,
            title: 'The Title',

            width:178,
            maxWidth:400,
            height: 100,
            minHeight: 100,
            items:
            [
            {
                title: 'Tab 1',
                xtype:'panel',
                items:
                    [{
                    xtype: 'datepicker',
                    minDate: new Date('12/15/2013'),
                    maxDate: new Date(),
                    // Disable dates is set to invert dates in array
                    disabledDates:["^(?!"+dateArray.join("|")+").*$"],
                    // disabledDates:["^("+dateArray.join("|")+").*$"],

                    handler: function(picker, date)
                            {

                            // do something with the selected date
                            // Ext.Msg.alert('date picker example in init2.js' + '<br>' + Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y'));

                            console.log('date picker example in init2.js' + Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y'));

                            // get store by unique storeId
                            var store = Ext.getStore('Users');

                            // clear current filters
                             store.clearFilter(true);

                            // filter store
                            store.filter("unix_time_stamp", Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y'));

                            // store.proxy.extraParams = { key:'test'};
                             store.load();
                            }
                    }]
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html: 'ers may be added dynamically  - Others may be added dynamically',
            }

            ]

            }
        ]

    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter records displayed in grid by selected date in date picker on the server side try to filter grid's store.

In your store configuration you need to set [`remoteFilter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-remoteFilter) config attribute to `true`. Then store proxy will automatically add filter params into store load data requests. Also if you have only one instance of this store, add to configuration unique [`storeId`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-storeId).

In your `datepicker` handler you need set store filter to selected date:

```
handler: function(picker, date)
{
    // get store by unique storeId
    var store = Ext.getStore('storeId');

    // clear current filters
    store.clearFilter(true);

    // filter store
    store.filter("unix_time_stamp", date);

}
```

Then on server side you need to parse and process filter param.

Comment: Thanks Akatum.  It looks like I need to add store.Load() to get my request sent to my server side? I am going to update my OP and add new snippet of date picker code.

Comment: If you have your store configured with `remoteFilter: true` it should calls `load()` automatically after you add new filter by `store.filter()` method.

Comment: Im not sure what is happening.  When I select the date from datepicker the request is made to my serv.  I see the filter param that is sent but at this point I am not using it.  I was expecting to see the query run on my server a second time and reload the grid with same data because it is unfiltered since i am not using the filter param.